# How to determine if a user has created a profile on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have been working on a view in which all of the users profiles are displayed but so that a user can see other peoples profiles in that page, the user has to first create a profile. So every user who has already created a profile can go to that page but if the user havent created one yet, then the user goes to a form  until it has a profile. To make this happen, I am using if statments to determine if the user has a profile or not but this is not working because every user is being redirected to the form part of the page even if the user has already a profile. How can this error be fixed, is there something wrong with the database? Is there other way to make these happen besides using if statements on the html?

models.py

```
    class Mates(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates')
        users_requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users_requests")
        req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
    def matesmain(request):
        contents = Mates.objects.all()
        context = {
            'contents': contents,
            'form_mates': MatesForm(),
        }
        print("nice3")
        return render(request, 'mates.html', context)

    def mates(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form_mates.is_valid():
                instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
                return redirect('mates-main')
                print('succesfully uploded')

        else:
            form_mates = MatesForm()
            print('didnt upload')
        context = {
            'form_mates': form_mates,
            'contents': Mates.objects.all()
        }
        return render(request, 'mates.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('mates', views.mates, name='mates'),
        path('mates-main', views.matesmain, name='mates-main'),

    ]
```

mates.html

```
    {% if not contents.user == user %}
        FORM GOES HERE
    {% elif contents.user == user %}
        {% for content in contents %}
            USER PROFILES HERE
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

If there are any questions or need to see more code please let me know in the comments:)

Comment: According to your `context` variable, `contents` is a queryset including all `Mates` objects. Querysets do not have attributes such as `user`. Imagine if you put this all on one line of python: `Mates.objects.all().user()`. What would you expect to see?

Comment: @AdamStarrh So I should add .user() right?

Comment: As I stated, that will result in an AttributeError as querysets are groups of objects and don't have their own data by default. You can try for yourself and see the result. You'll need to find a way to select the user you want either using `.filter()`, or by looping over the queryset.

Comment: @AdamStarrh Hey I used .filter(user=request.user) and now it only shows the profile from the logedin user

Comment: @AdamStarrh will  using a for loop on views.py like `for user in Mates:` work? will that make the html if statements work?

Answer (score 0):

Mates.objects.all() is returning you every User in your database, but objects.all() doesn't have a method called .user(), you should use something like:

```
Mate.objects.get(name__exact='username')
```

You could look a the django docs to know more about how to make queries
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Hey! so just by changing  mates.objects.all() to Mates.objects.get(name__exact="username") the if statements on the html will work?

Comment: I don't have all your code nor your database, you have to read the docs and use the methods get() or filter() to your particular case, 'name' and ' username' are placeholder so you understand the example

Comment: I was checking migrations and I realized that the object which is refered as user on Mates model is named user_request in the migration file How can I correct that?